# Xpath to select second text match instead of first one and selecting next element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to select an element that has random generated class so my only way to select that element is using `xpath`.

The element I need to select is an `input` box with the previous label "City" but the problem is that it appears three times on the website and I want to select the second match on the website.

I have tried this, but it only selects the first one.

```
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input")
```

To select the second one I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input")[1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also add the html source for the element?

Comment: I see a typo in the cpath, try this may be `(//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input)[2]`. So the complete line will be `input = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input)[2]")`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an 's' in `find_element_by_xpath`. Try `find_elements_by_xpath`.

```
input = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input")[1]
```

You can make sure there are expected 3 instances that match this xpath with some thing like:

```
input_all = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input")
print("len(input_all):", len(input_all))
```

Comment: Isn't he asking to locate one element? why `find_elements_by_xpath` in this case?

Comment: @Dhamo according to what is stated above 3 elements match the xpath given above but when he tried to find the second one it failed.  Attempting to locate the second element with `find_element_by_xpath....)[1]` will fail. So with out access to the html I suggested `find_elements_by_xpath` be used.

Comment: Well, more than an answer, this one seems to be a way to ensure the given xpath is right to match all 3 elements.

Comment: @Dhamo if the assumption that the xpath matches exactly three elements is correct the first part of my answer will work.  If this assumption is false the second part of my answer can be used to find the desired index.

Comment: Yes, agree that `find_elements_by_xpath` will locate the first matching element (City1) even it has more matches (City2, City3). The recommended solution is always locate the right element to avoid further reworks (say for eg. if City 0 gets added).  But you are right, without the html, we can offer only such solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This would get only the second match:

```
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'City')][2]/input")
```

Answer (score 0):

if at all you are looking to get second matching element, you may try

WebElement input = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'City')]//following::input")).get(1)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the following XPath fulfill your needs :

```
(//input[preceding::label[1][contains(.,"City")]])[2]
```

Select the 2nd `input` element on the page which respect the following condition : is preceded by a `label` element containing a specific text.